# New to asp and don't understand why my text boxes are not visible

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Goal: Link html web page to Microsoft access file. This access file is very large and has columns titled: customer name, order number, street address, tracking number, and verified date. For the webpage we'd like asp textboxes and buttons that will search the microsoft access file in the back end.

We are using microsoft expression 4 to write the .aspx file and it renders correctly how we want in the design view. However, after copying the code (.aspx file) and placing it into notepadd ++ and saving it as an html file the buttons are not visible in the browser window. How can I convert the .aspx file to render on a browser? Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<% @ Page Language="C#" %> 
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Returns Received Report</title>

<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    font-size: xlarge;
}
.auto-style2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.auto-style3 {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.auto-style4 {
    margin-left: 280px;
}

.auto-style5 {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="auto-style2">
&nbsp;<body bgcolor="#black"><p></p>
    <div class="auto-style2">
<br />

<br />
<strong><span class="auto-style1"><u>Search for a Return:</u><br/>
        <br />
</span></strong>
    </div>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="auto-style4">
    <asp:TextBox id="Customer" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="261px" CssClass="auto-style5" Height="22px" BackColor="Black" BorderColor="Black"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Visible="true" PostBackUrl="Customer.aspx" Text="Search by Customer" BorderStyle="Outset" />
        </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox id="PO" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="261px" EnableViewState="True"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button id="Button2" runat="server" Visible="true" PostBackUrl="Order Number.aspx" Text="Search by Order Number" BorderStyle="Outset" Width="181px" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox id="ADDRESS" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="261px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button id="Button3" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Street_Address.aspx" Text="Search by Street Address" BorderStyle="Outset" Width="181px" />
    <br />
    <p>
    <asp:TextBox id="TrackingNumber" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="261px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button id="Button4" runat="server" PostBackUrl="TrackingNumber.aspx" Text="Search by Tracking Number" BorderStyle="Outset" Width="181px" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <asp:TextBox id="VerifiedDate" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="261px" CssClass="auto-style3"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button id="Button5" runat="server" PostBackUrl="TrackingNumber.aspx" Text="Search by Verified Date" BorderStyle="Outset" Width="181px" />
    </p>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
</form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: HTML is not interpret as ASP.Net code. That will never work.

Comment: apparently, you are not satisfied with reponses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529455/asp-net-controls-not-visible-in-ie8 . You need server-side .NET framework to execute. `<asp:TextBox` tags are meaningless to browsers.

Comment: Okay, so can you please direct me in the right direction on how I can take the files from microsoft expression and get them to render in a browser?

Comment: @ Igor, I appreciate your help I'm just very new to asp and web development and kind of had this project thrown at me. Are you saying that I should get: http://www.asp.net/get-started/websites for it to work?

Comment: @dkwalker2392 - you need to deploy your application to IIS with ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stated goal is to link your web pages to your Access databases. This is possible, but you'll need to do quite a bit of groundwork first. Yes, check out the Getting Started tutorials on asp.net, microsoftvirtualacademy.com, and so on.

However, you seem to be missing the basics. A HTML file is something that can be double-clicked on your desktop, and it will open up in a browser. An ASP.net page is designed to run on the server.

What this means is that when it's requested from the server, a certain amount of processing is done first, and then the server will generate the HTML that gets sent to your browser. This gives the server the ability to query your Access database, receive input, process input, and generate HTML on demand.

On Windows, you'll likely use something like IIS. If you download Visual Studio or WebMatrix, it will run a development server for you to test your code. When you're ready to deploy, you'll need a server (either locally, on your network, or from a third party hosting provider) for anyone to be able to see your pages.

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

.aspx files are template files that the server will populate with the data defined by the ASP calls. Renaming the file to html will not allow for the server to use the ASP calls, as they are no longer being processed by the server.

Comment: This is the problem, but not a solution... care to elaborate? :)

Comment: Can you not use it as *.aspx? Why do you need to convert it if it's displaying correctly? Other options to populate the data into a web page may not be a simple. If you are trying to eliminate the ASP framework from the site, you would still need a mechanism to populate the page with.

Comment: We were hoping to be able to create a web page that our agents can go to in order make their necessary searches. But confused on moving it from microsoft expression to a browser.

Comment: @dkwalker2392: You can't go from Expression to a "browser". You need to go to a webserver, which provides pages for a browser. Basically you need to have some basics of web development in order to solve the stated problem.

Comment: @dkwalker2392 aspx requires an ASP.net backend to process the pages. You may want to look into straight html / javascript to perform the functions you are looking for. Look into JQuery also.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help! This helps me greatly!

Comment: @dkwalker2392 Glad to help....keep us posted if you succeed.